# Hide fields on the user profile page with preprocess function

Tags: 7, users, theming, forms

On the user profile edit page I can do something like this in my theme's template.php file to hide a field:

```
function MYTHEME_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form,$form_state,$form_id){
//remove unwanted fields from the form (default value is still saved)
  $form['timezone']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

On the profile view page, I am trying to do a similar thing. I want to hide:

```
History
Member for 3 months 4 weeks
```

So I [looked up the api function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_view/7) and it's `hook_user_view`

Based on this I try:

```
function MYTHEME_user_view($items) {
$items['member_for']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

... however, this does not work after I clear the cache. I'd also like to avoid hiding this using CSS `display:none`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to use any preprocess functions tbh :> its pretty simple
Go to `Home » Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings » Manage Display` , History -> `Format`  chose hidden.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I actually have never used that page before, never had a need to until now. :)